# Flex multi-client live updates

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, flex4, amfphp

At work we use amfphp as server and mysql as databse. What we need is that when a user updates a record the other users logged in the application can receive that update and see the update data, is that possible? Are there any libraries capable of doing this? I think that the most important part is to identify from the server the logged in users... thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this happen you will need to use a server that supports push functionality; meaning the server can send data to the client.

[LiveCycle](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/) supports this, as does [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org) and [WebOrb](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products.html). I don't think that PHP does.